# MailItem.Save() error "The operation cannot be performed because the message has been changed"

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I got a problem with saving mailitem in Outlook addin, after I change or add some properties to it. Code throws error: "The operation cannot be performed because the message has been changed". The idea of add-in is: right click on Mail, click new option "Send to system", then mail is sent and it gets icon as a mark that it was successfully sent.
Here is my code:

```
mail.UserProperties.Add("exportedToCompany", OlUserPropertyType.olText, true, OlFormatText.olFormatTextText);
mail.UserProperties["exportedToCompany"].Value = "exported";

try
{
    try
    {
        mail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8582000B", false);
        mail.MessageClass = "IPM.Note.ExportedMail";
        mail.Save(); //throws error
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex) { logger.Error(ex.Message); logger.Error(ex.StackTrace); }
    DeleteUselessMsg(mail);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    logger.Error(ex.Message); 
    logger.Error(ex.StackTrace);
}

SendMail(GetNextMail());
```

During debug, I can't really simulate situation when it happens, I just got log file from client where this error happens a lot.
I'm wondering why is to so random, that I don't get this error at all and client get it a lot, but not every time. One of my ideas was that IMAP is somehow updating mails before I save them - is it even possible?
Other thing after code executes with error: Outlook asks to save unsaved items after you try to close program, and supposendly program creates copies of mail in drafts folder (but I'm not sure if is it connected with my problem). Can I somehow force save on MailItem?
Using Outlook 2013

Answer (score 1):

The error means the message was modified between the time you opened it and the time your called Save. As a general rule of thumb, make sure you keep references to live Outlook items for as short period of time as possible.

Where does the mail variable come from? Try to store the item's entry id instead of the live MailItem object: open the item by its entry id using `Application.Session.GetItemFromID`, modify and save it, release the item.

Comment: mail variable comes from Explorer.Selection od type MailItem

Comment: As you said, problem occurs when message is modified between open and save action, but I modify it every time when I add UserProperties for example, shouldn't it throws error every time then?

Comment: No, the underlying MAPI provider will see a conflict only when the message is saved. It is perfectly fine to modify a message but never save it.